# Reassign index of dataframe without adding column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Trying to make the 'time' column into the index and drop the old index so I can concat. Problem is when I reassign index it moves 'time' to the beginning and adds the old index as an Unnamed column.

So far I've tried

`df.drop('Untitled: 0.1')` *how it appears on the csv

Then I tried this but it still does nothing to the column

`df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

`df = df.set_index('time')`

Lastly I tried this (which did get rid of the column)
but it also reset the index and added another column as index, so when I made 'time' the index again I was back in the same position.

`df = df.iloc[:,[0,2,3,4,5,6]]`

here is the code and some examples of df:

```
            df = pd.read_csv(file_path + '/' + ticker)
            df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
            df = df.set_index('time')
            df.to_csv(file_path + '/' + ticker)
            df = pd.read_csv(file_path + '/' + ticker)
            df = df.iloc[:,[0,2,3,4,5,6]]
            print(df)
            quit()
```

```
           time   open   high    low  close   volume
0    1554336000   4.12   4.13   3.96   4.11   213783
1    1554422400   3.97   4.09   3.85   3.97   313422
2    1554681600   3.91   4.03   3.86   3.99   134396
3    1554768000   3.97   4.06   3.89   3.97    35463
4    1554854400   3.97   4.13   3.95   4.10   178473
395  1603756800  13.99  14.31  13.84  13.98   615619
396  1603843200  13.59  13.76  13.27  13.38   513077
397  1603929600  13.39  13.89  13.33  13.55   911940
398  1604016000  13.40  13.59  12.55  12.89  1255169
399  1604275200  13.13  13.14  12.40  12.73  1004683
```

csv content (starting)

```
,open,high,low,close,volume,time
399,12.420000076294000,12.930000305176000,12.420000076294000,12.750000000000000,716193,1554336000
398,12.770000457764000,13.000000000000000,12.689999580383000,12.720000267028999,404353,1554422400
397,12.699999809265000,12.899999618530000,12.260000228882001,12.500000000000000,639136,1554681600
396,12.390000343322999,12.479999542236000,11.899999618530000,12.060000419617000,849788,1554768000
395,12.100000381470000,12.420000076294000,11.979999542236000,12.300000190735000,404267,1554854400
394,12.329999923706000,12.409999847412000,12.180000305176000,12.369999885559000,293689,1554940800
393,12.500000000000000,13.239999771117999,12.470000267028999,13.090000152588000,947110,1555027200
392,12.750000000000000,12.760000228882001,12.100000381470000,12.359999656677001,1121387,1555286400
391,12.359999656677001,12.880000114441000,12.359999656677001,12.640000343322999,613414,1555372800
390,12.829999923706000,12.949999809265000,12.350000381470000,12.569999694824000,609524,1555459200
389,12.520000457764000,12.829999923706000,12.520000457764000,12.590000152588000,349691,1555545600
388,12.460000038147000,12.539999961853000,12.060000419617000,12.369999885559000,630388,1555891200
387,12.409999847412000,12.579999923706000,12.300000190735000,12.399999618530000,460863,1555977600
386,12.399999618530000,12.810000419617000,12.239999771117999,12.779999732971001,493512,1556064000
385,12.750000000000000,12.750000000000000,12.329999923706000,12.409999847412000,370835,1556150400
384,12.409999847412000,12.649999618530000,12.300000190735000,12.579999923706000,405826,1556236800
383,12.609999656677001,12.699999809265000,12.430000305176000,12.439999580383000,264683,1556496000
382,12.420000076294000,12.539999961853000,12.220000267028999,12.520000457764000,337222,1556582400
381,12.590000152588000,12.779999732971001,12.250000000000000,12.270000457764000,617602,1556668800
380,12.289999961853000,12.550000190735000,11.869999885559000,12.090000152588000,719905,1556755200
379,12.100000381470000,12.630000114441000,12.050000190735000,12.600000381470000,574398,1556841600
378,12.250000000000000,12.750000000000000,12.189999580383000,12.689999580383000,493273,1557100800
377,12.500000000000000,12.630000114441000,12.010000228882001,12.079999923706000,799438,1557187200
376,12.069999694824000,12.340000152588000,11.899999618530000,12.060000419617000,1155857,1557273600
375,11.119999885559000,11.600000381470000,10.430000305176000,10.930000305176000,2239596,1557360000
374,10.810000419617000,11.060000419617000,10.300000190735000,10.710000038147000,965198,1557446400
373,10.369999885559000,10.449999809265000,9.920000076294000,10.159999847412000,830895,1557705600
372,10.250000000000000,10.529999732971000,10.189999580383000,10.380000114441000,600230,1557792000
371,10.250000000000000,10.430000305176000,9.989999771118198,10.010000228882001,601777,1557878400
```

csv content after making `time` index

```
time,Unnamed: 0,open,high,low,close,volume
1554336000,399,4.1199998855591,4.1300001144409,3.960000038147,4.1100001335144,213783
1554422400,398,3.9700000286102,4.0900001525879,3.8499999046326,3.9700000286102,313422
1554681600,397,3.910000085830701,4.0300002098083,3.859999895095799,3.9900000095367,134396
1554768000,396,3.9700000286102,4.0599999427795,3.890000104904201,3.9700000286102,35463
1554854400,395,3.9700000286102,4.1300001144409,3.9500000476837,4.0999999046326,178473
1554940800,394,4.1100001335144,4.1300001144409,4.0199999809265,4.0700001716614,121793
1555027200,393,4.0999999046326,4.0999999046326,3.9000000953674,3.9700000286102,155920
1555286400,392,4.0,4.0300002098083,3.4000000953674,3.5099999904633,521614
1555372800,391,3.5999999046326,3.7599999904633,3.5999999046326,3.6800000667572,223112
1555459200,390,3.7000000476837,3.710000038147,3.25,3.289999961853,297053
1555545600,389,3.3699998855591,3.4500000476837003,3.2799999713898,3.390000104904201,73880
1555891200,388,3.4500000476837003,3.5299999713898,3.390000104904201,3.4300000667572004,86210
1555977600,387,3.4500000476837003,3.5899999141692995,3.4400000572205003,3.5099999904633,170755
1556064000,386,3.539999961853,3.5499999523163,3.460000038147,3.5,76236
1556150400,385,3.4800000190735,3.5199999809265,3.3699998855591,3.4700000286102,52747
1556236800,384,3.4700000286102,3.5499999523163,3.420000076294,3.5099999904633,56448
1556496000,383,3.5499999523163,3.579999923706,3.4000000953674,3.460000038147,122287
1556582400,382,3.5199999809265,3.5299999713898,3.410000085830701,3.5,132701
1556668800,381,3.4900000095367,3.5,3.4300000667572004,3.460000038147,66950
1556755200,380,3.4500000476837003,3.4500000476837003,3.329999923706,3.359999895095799,78391
1556841600,379,3.359999895095799,3.539999961853,3.359999895095799,3.4900000095367,40613
1557100800,378,3.4800000190735,3.5899999141692995,3.460000038147,3.5499999523163,107244
1557187200,377,3.460000038147,3.5299999713898,3.410000085830701,3.5,64557
1557273600,376,3.5,3.5599999427795,3.4500000476837003,3.5,47465
1557360000,375,3.460000038147,3.6500000953674,3.4000000953674,3.609999895095799,198191
1557446400,374,3.5899999141692995,3.660000085830701,3.5099999904633,3.579999923706,52656
1557705600,373,3.5499999523163,3.5499999523163,3.4500000476837003,3.4900000095367,125606
1557792000,372,3.5099999904633,3.539999961853,3.410000085830701,3.5099999904633,57442
1557878400,371,3.4900000095367,3.5299999713898,3.390000104904201,3.5199999809265,47811
1557964800,370,3.4700000286102,3.539999961853,3.410000085830701,3.410000085830701,65141
1558051200,369,3.4000000953674,3.4800000190735,3.390000104904201,3.460000038147,44106
1558310400,368,3.5199999809265,3.539999961853,3.3099999427795,3.4500000476837003,100222
1558396800,367,3.4500000476837003,3.5499999523163,3.2699999809265,3.3399999141692995,154912
1558483200,366,3.3800001144409,3.4900000095367,3.3099999427795,3.359999895095799,36900
```

Comment: Remove the 'reset_index(drop=True)' statement and use 'set_index' to overwrite the original index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you really need to provide the CSV content to make this answerable, but you could try using the `index_col` argument to [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path + '/' + ticker, index_col=["time"])
df = df.iloc[:,[0,2,3,4,5,6]]
print(df)
```

You may also want to consider the `usecols` argument if you only need a subset of columns.

Comment: with this I am getting an `raise IndexError("positional indexers are out-of-bounds")
IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds` error. I've added some of the csv data now.

Comment: I need all of the named columns, but the 1st (unnamed) index column was added for some reason.